# aztfexport storage failed with error network.ServiceEndpointPoliciesClient

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to export the existing resources in Azure by using the Azure Terrafy when am doing this am facing with the below error

> Error: retrieving Subnet Service Endpoint Storage Policy
> "_e41f87a2_mi_xxx" (Resource Group "xxxx"):
> network.ServiceEndpointPoliciesClient#Get: Failure responding to
> request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Error occurred
> unmarshalling JSON
>
> Error = 'json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field
> ServiceEndpointPolicyPropertiesFormat.contextualServiceEndpointPolicies
> of type "id":
> "/subscriptions/4xxxx/resourceGroups/xx/providers/Microsoft.Network/serviceEndpointPolicies/e41xxx
> Error: retrieving Subnet Service Endpoint Storage Policy
> network.ServiceEndpointPoliciesClient#Get: Failure responding to
> request: Error = 'json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field
> ServiceEndpointPolicyPropertiesFormat.contextualServiceEndpointPolicies
> of type

Comment: please share the terraform code you tried @balaganesh and also make changes in query format

Comment: Am trying to import the existing azure resources using aztfexport

Comment: what are the resources you try to import please share the code you're using

Comment: Aztfexport resourcegroup resourcegroupname

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to export the existing resources in Azure by using the aztf export and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The blocker mentioned with Azure Terrafy appears to be related to issues with JSON unmarshalling when retrieving a Subnet Service Endpoint Storage Policy. This error typically indicates that the JSON response from the Azure API is not in the expected format, or there's a mismatch between the data structure expected by the Azure Terrafy tool and the actual data structure provided by Azure.

I tried a demo version to import Azure resources in the state using the aztfexport.

[image]

These are the preexisting resources I was trying to export using aztfexport.

[image]

**Output in the local:**

[image]

Comment: How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What is the version you're using @balaganesh

Comment: C:\Users\balmur>aztfexport --version
aztfexport version dev

C:\Users\balmur>